# window.opener.document refers to different tab of window instead of source window

Tags: javascript, window

I have an online application that has a page with data like customer First, Last name. 
It also has "edit" link which opens a different window, where this data can be edited and submitted.

On submit button click from new window, the newly opened window will be closed and changed data would reflect on the original source window.

Now, I am opening same application and same page in two different tabs of Window IE 8.

When I click on edit link for 1st tab, it opens an EDIT window. I change some data and without submitting data from the EDIT window, I am going to second tab and clicking edit link. This is meant to replace the existing EDIT window.

I am changing data in this new EDIT window and submitting. **This should reflect changes in second tab (from where it is opened), but it reflects changes in first tab.**

From code perspective, I am storing the newly entered data from EDIT window to elements like `window.opener.document.nameInfo.elementX`.

Any idea why window.opener.document gives reference to first tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it every time you open the edit window when edit link got clicked.

```
var w = window.open('url...', 'name...');
w.opener = window;
```